# Do infant seats in the EU have a "suitable for aircraft" label on them?

Tags: air-travel, europe, seating, child-safety-seats

Do infant/toddler car seats (not boosters) in the EU market have a "suitable for aircraft use" testing/labeling process, akin to that for [AU/NZS](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60425/how-can-one-use-a-child-car-seat-that-requires-a-top-tether-in-an-airplane) or [FMVSS/CMVSS](http://www.faa.gov/passengers/fly_children/) seats?  It is alright if such testing/labeling is a manufacturer's option -- I just want to know if such a thing exists in the EU, as lap children aren't nearly as crashworthy as even a 9-G (old standard) airline seat, while a certified and properly installed CRS should perform adequately even to the newer 16-G standard for airline seating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the European Aviation Safety Agency, a [FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20190316003532/https://www.easa.europa.eu/faq/19167) on child car seats for flights states the following:

> Regarding the use of a car seat as an acceptable child restraint
> device, this is regulated under the Regulation on Air Operations,
> through Annex IV (Part CAT), specifically CAT.IDE.A.205. The basis for
> the provision on child restraint devices is JAR-OPS 1 guidance
> material.
>
> To conclude, the proposed examples for acceptable child restraint
> devices include car seats, and item 2 of AMC1 CAT.IDE.A.205 lists the
> standards with which the CRD should comply. This includes the UN
> standard ECE R 44, -03 or later series - this is commonly indicated on
> the car seat's label.

Information regarding this standard is available from a car seat manufacturer [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180402113844/http://www.maxi-cosi.com:80/us-en/car-seats/traveling-safely-with-children-in-car-seats/child-car-seat-laws-and-regulations/ece-r44-04-label.aspx).

> Warning: from April 2008, all child car seats that were manufactured
> before 1995 and approved to the ECE R44/01 and 44/02 standard are no
> longer legal and must not be used or sold. Only seats displaying the
> European Standard orange label, indicating approval to the Standard to
> ECE R44/03, ECE R 44/04 or i-Size (UN R129) may be legally used.

It appears that the current standard version is R44/04 and should look like this:

[image]

Source: maxi-cosi.com (external link from above site)

Note that the FAQ also states that you must check with each individual airline:

> In the first instance, passengers wishing to use their car seat as a
> child restraint device (CRD) on board an aircraft should contact the
> airline or travel agency through which the ticket has been booked, in
> order to obtain information on which CRDs are acceptable and also to
> ensure that the car seat can be installed properly on the seat of the
> particular aircraft with which they will fly.

For example, BA [states](https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/family-travel/seating):

> If you have paid for a separate seat for your infant, or your child is
> under 3 years, you can bring your own **forward facing** car seat to
> secure into the aircraft seat.
>
> The car seat:
>
> - can only be used for infants over six months old and children up to three years old
> - must be designed to be secured by means of a normal aircraft single lap strap and face the same direction as the passenger seat on
>   which it is positioned
> - must have a 5-point restraining harness
> - must not exceed the dimensions of the aircraft seat, and should fit into an area of 45cm x 45cm (17.5ins x 17.5ins)
> - must be strapped in place ensuring that the adult lap strap buckle does not lie directly over any part of the frame or under the
>   structure of the car type seat after tightening